# Angular - How to initiate FormArray from an existing array?

Tags: angular, forms, datatable, formarray

I would like to create an editable table with `FormArray`.

For this, I have the `results` attribute that is rendered in the table.

What's the proper way to initialize it with `FormArray` data?

```ts
results: Array;
tableForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
    arrayForm: this.fb.array([])
  });
}
```

Comment: not sure, but if you're referring to the idea of creating a reactive form based on an existing interface. it's not possible yet.

Comment: @Stavm yes it is, but it's not what's asked.

Comment: No, I wanna initiate formarray from existing array. 'results' is an array, I wanna put all the date to a FormArray.

Comment: @Maryannah i'd love a reference .

Comment: @Liem you can check this: https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/ it explains it quite well

Comment: @Stavm https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6p9gqk

Comment: @Stavm, Thanks, I'll check

Comment: @Maryannah this is by no mean a form creation based on an interface. please read through [angular feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13721)

Comment: @Stavm and this is not an issue about creating a form from an interface, but a request to be able to type a form. But IMO it would be useless to create a form from an interface, since the form is an object instance that the user will fill. Creating it from a class is okay, creating it from an interface would be useless.

Comment: @Liem I'm removing my answer and trying to answer your comment on it !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A form array is a bundle of form controls (as a reminder, a form group is a form control).

In the following I will assume your results are model-related, such as

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 'title 1' },
  { id: 2, title: 'title 2' },
]
```

(If not, feel free to explain to me what the results are)

Since a form array must accept controls, you will have to map your results to comply with the signature.

You can do it with this :

```
ngOnInit(private fb: FormBuilder) {
 this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
   arrayForm: this.fb.array(this.results.map(r => this.fb.group(r)))
 });
}
```

With this, your form array will contain a form group, made of all the properties in your object.

Is this what you wanted or not ?

Comment: why are you passing the FormBuilder as a parameter on the ngOnInit instead of injecting it in the constructor?

Answer (score 4):

You can create an array based on the OBJECT(not an interface).

I actually wrote a [small demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbufqb?file=src/app/app.component.html) a few days ago:

**our OBJECT (!):**

```
 valueFromBackend = {
    propOne: 'X',
    propTwo: 'Y',
    propArray: [
      {
        objPropA: 'a',
        objPropB: 'b'
      },
      {
        objPropA: 'c',
        objPropB: 'd'
      },
      {
        objPropA: 'e',
        objPropB: 'f'
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    const count = this.valueFromBackend.propArray.length

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      propOne: '',
      propTwo: '',
      propArray: this.fb.array([...this.createItems(count)])
    });

    // dynamically set value
    this.myForm.setValue(this.valueFromBackend);
  }

  private createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      objPropA: '',
      objPropB: '',
    });
  }

  private createItems(count: number): FormGroup[] {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      arr.push(this.createItem());
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="propArray" *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('propArray').controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <input formControlName="objPropA" placeholder="Item name">
      <input formControlName="objPropB" placeholder="Item description">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```